# Curb gem broke my Bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cloud9-ide, curb

I am making contact form in rails app and when tried to `bundle install` i got error from gem i never added to gemfile. Some mysterious `curb gem` lack some libraries or something else.

I have looked for answers but can't figure out what they are saying, because of their platforms. I use `Cloud9` `linux` environment with `rails 4.2.0`

Maybe some of you have ideas how to fix this? bellow is full error message.

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150504-13714-unpe0g.rb extconf.rb 
>   checking for curl-config... no
>   checking for main() in -lcurl... no
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>   Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
>           --with-curl-dir
>           --without-curl-dir
>           --with-curl-include
>           --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
>           --with-curl-lib
>           --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
>           --with-curllib
>           --without-curllib
>   extconf.rb:18:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)
>     Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
>     options to extconf.
>   extconf failed, exit code 1
>   Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/curb-0.8.8 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/curb-0.8.8/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing curb (0.8.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that`gem install curb -v '0.8.8'` succeeds before bundling.

And here is my `gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.0'
gem 'sass',         '3.4.13'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'mailgun-rails', '~> 0.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `gemfile`?

Comment: Your bundle was fine before adding `mailgun-rails`?  Maybe try taking the version off and seeing if it installs properly (with the latest version). If that works, you can always use `bundle show` to find the version and then set it in your gem file.

Comment: Thanks, yes the `mailgun` was the problem. Now, knowing that, maybe you have suggestions how can i use Mailgan services without gem?

Comment: Is it for a simple contact form?  On a recent project, I used `gem mail-form,1.5` but I am sure there are other choices.  Were you not able to get your bundle installed with the latest version of `mailgun`?

Comment: i made simplest contact form posible, but now am trying to make it work in production. Can't figure out those environment configurations.

Comment: Since curl is missing, did you try doing `apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and then running bundle install again?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `Gemfile.lock` file located right next to the actual `Gemfile` and then running `bundle install`.

If that fails you could try dumping your current gemlist (e.g. imploding `rvm`) and installing them again.